# Insert LinkedList values into database

Tags: java, mysql, database

Here is my LinkedList

```
LinkedList<Location> locationData = new LinkedList<>();
```

Here is my Location class variables

```
public class Location {

    String SA3Code;
    String name;

}
```

**QUESTION: I want to insert this locationData LinkedList inside method**

*List of **SA3Code** and **name** values should insert into database*

I've tried to insert values as following, but it gives an error of "Data too long"

```
 public void InsertLocations(LinkedList<Location> locationData) throws SQLException {

    for (int i = 0; i < locationData.size(); i++) {
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO HomelessInfo.Location (SA3Code, Name) VALUES ('locationData.get(i).SA3Code', 'locationData.get(i).name')");
    }
    connection.close();
}
```

ERROR

```html
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'SA3Code' at row 1
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1335)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2108)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
 at Homeless.DatabaseUtility.InsertLocations(DatabaseUtility.java:42)
 at Homeless.DataFile.readRecords(DataFile.java:98)
 at Homeless.COIT20256Assignment2.main(COIT20256Assignment2.java:20)
/Users/SK/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2rc/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinkedList locationData;
```

The above variable is the list so you need to loop the list and made a 'N' Number of sql Query Based on linked list size and execute the query

```
 public void InsertLocations(LinkedList locationData) throws SQLException {
        connection.open();
        for(customObject : locationData){
         StringBuilder sqlquery = new StringBuilder();
         sql.append("INSERT INTO HomelessInfo.Location (SA3Code, Name) VALUES ('").append(customObject.column1).append("','").append(customObject.column2).append("'");
        statement.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
        }
        connection.close();

}
```

Based on your error I found out Some time
 -May be your Database Column - **SA3Code** is small size like varchar. if your data size is huge than your column length your got the following issue, so please update your column datatype based on your need. 
Please Ref the following Data Types
[image: Database Data Types]

Thanks

Comment: I've edited my question. Can you please check it.Thank you!

Comment: @user8602973 If Possible Please Update Your Full Error Message. So i will help you based on your error statement

Comment: Done. I've added the Error message @sridharlovevirus

Comment: @user8602973  if SA3Code column is varchar means change the data type to blob or following long data type https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-data-types.aspx/

Comment: @user8602973  please update question status as answered. it's useful for others thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found answer and it worked

```html
 public void InsertLocations(LinkedList<Location> locationData) throws SQLException {

        for (int i = 0; i < locationData.size(); i++) {
            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO HomelessInfo.Location (SA3Code, Name) VALUES ('"+locationData.get(i).SA3Code+"', '"+locationData.get(i).name+"')");
        }
        connection.close();

}
```